# Putting if else condition in subquery during INSERT

Tags: oracle, if-statement, insert, subquery

```
SELECT CODE * STATUS_CODE WHERE CODE IN (.....);
```

Above SQL is a subquery embedded in an `insert` statement to determine a column `CLOSE_CODE` to 'Y' (if query return) or 'N' (if query no return).

How can I put the query something like `IF ELSE` condition in the insert statement?

```
INSERT INTO CODE_REVIEWS (CLOSE_CODE) 
VALUES (....)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with [`NVL()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm). Rewrite the query, so that it returns 'Y' if a record exists. Select `'Y'`from `DUAL` and use [`EXISTS`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions012.htm) for that. If no such row exists, the result of the subquery will be `NULL` and `NVL()` will turn that `NULL` into `'N'`.

```
NVL((SELECT 'Y'
            FROM DUAL
            WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                                 FROM STATUS_CODE
                                 WHERE CODE IN (....))),
    'N')
```

A more verbose version, which would also work in many other DBMS could use [`CASE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) and again `EXISTS`. `WHEN` such rows exists, `'Y'`will be returned, `ELSE` `'N'`.

```
CASE
  WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM STATUS_CODE
                      WHERE CODE IN (...))
    THEN 'Y'
  ELSE
    'N'
END
```

Comment: i will choose `NVL()` as i am working on Oracle,thanks!